# Parallax Scrolling different shape

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, parallax

I'm developing a web site and this is the first time I'm using parallax scrolling, so I made a layout that the divs has a different shape and I want to know if somebody know how I could do that.

Bellow is how I want it

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone got a decent answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an answer.
Take a look on the site I've made, http://jacksonueda.com.br/alfaline/

I used shape-outside property in CSS:

```
shape-outside: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, -200% 50%);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, -200% 50%);
```